# Text area expanding to fill vertically: works on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to create a `textarea` that expands vertically to fill all empty space in a div except for a fixed height offset from above and a fix height offset from below.  The following CSS does the trick for Chrome, but not Firefox. In Firefox the `textarea` gets what looks like a default height and just stays that large, leaving extra empty space below. Any suggestions to have the Chrome behavior in all browsers?

```
#add-comment-text
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 99%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2to0upmz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [css calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#add-comment-pane
{
  height: 100%;
}

#add-comment-header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#add-comment-text
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 99%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px); <!-- HERE -->
}

#add-comment-button
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="add-comment-pane">
    <div class="unselectable" id="add-comment-header">
        Comment on:
        <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax" style="text-decoration: none" target="_blank">markdown</a>.
    </div>
    <textarea id="add-comment-text"></textarea>
    <button class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="add-comment-button">Post Comment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Never heard of calc.  Great tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height` to your `textarea`:

```
#add-comment-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 99%;
  height:85%;
}
```

Comment: height indeed works, but it is still strange why bottom doesn't :O (at least to me)

Comment: Height don't work exactly for me because, like the JSFiddle UI, my outermost div is in a panel that can be dragged to re-size.  So, like in the JSFiddle, if you drag the horizontal bar that defines the HTML area you can get into states where the button is on top of the `textarea` (small window) or the `textarea` isn't gobbling up all the vertical space (large window). I agree height would work if the dimensions of the surrounding area were unchanging.